# Listar pasta de ftp com php

Tags: php, ftp

Boa tarde pessoal, podem ajudar?
Desejo listar todos os arquivos em uma pasta de uma conexão ftp com php, estou usando este código:

```
// Dados do servidor
$servidor = 'server'; // Endereço
$usuario = 'user'; // Usuário
$senha = 'pass'; // Senha

// Abre a conexão com o servidor FTP
$ftpconn = ftp_connect($servidor); // Retorno: true ou false

// Faz o login no servidor FTP
$login = ftp_login($ftpconn, $usuario, $senha); // Retorno: true ou false

// Informa sucesso ou não da conexão
if (isset($login)) {
    echo "conectado";
}else{
    echo "não conectado";
}

// Recebe lista dos arquivos do ftp
$lista = ftp_nlist($ftpconn, '/');

// Imprime var_dump
var_dump($lista);

// Imprime foreach
foreach ($lista as $item) {
    echo $item . "<br />";
}

// Fecha conexão ftp
ftp_close($ftpconn);
```

Usando ftp_rawlist ou ftp_nlist, o vardump me retorna: bool(false), e o print_r retorna nada. Podem ajudar?

A conexão é bem sucedida, consigo criar pasta, apagar, etc. O problema é só com o listar mesmo...

Comment: O codigo parece estar certo, tente listar o diretorio atual ao inves do / para vermos o que acontece. `$lista = ftp_nlist($ftpconn, '.');`

Comment: Olá amigo, obrigado pela resposta. Mas problema persiste. Procurei também tentar listar outra pasta e nada.
$lista = ftp_nlist($ftpconn, '.');
$lista = ftp_nlist($ftpconn, '');
$lista = ftp_nlist($ftpconn, '/novapasta/');
$lista = ftp_nlist($ftpconn, 'novapasta/');

Comment: Existe pemissão de leitura na pasta? Acredite, é possivel gravar sem ter permissao de leitura.

Comment: Acessando pelo filezilla com as mesmas credenciais, tenho total acesso as pastas e arquivos. Verificando as permissões, elas são 755 para todas as pastas. Uma informação adicional, executei este código no apache5 e 7. Ambos informam o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Bem, a necessidade era listar estes arquivos do ftp e depois fazer algumas ações neles. Pensei na idéia de baixar todos os arquivos do ftp para uma pasta local, listá-los e depois fazer o que é necessário. Farei isso, tendo sucesso posto o código aqui para todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente habilitar o modo de listagem passivo:

```
// Habilita o modo Passivo
ftp_pasv($ftpconn, true);

// Recebe lista dos arquivos do ftp
$lista = ftp_nlist($ftpconn, '/');

// Imprime var_dump
var_dump($lista);
```

Comment: Sucesso! Muito obrigado amigo!